# Is there a way to force RoboHelp html topic list index into a single file?

Tags: menu, tags, robohelp

We're currently using RoboHelp 8 in a Windows 7 64-Bit environment. When we output our files to WebHelp, RoboHelp automatically creates a series of files, `whlsti*.htm` where * is a sequential file number. These files live in the following path: `Output\Production\WebHelp\whgdata` and are generated from the entries in the Topic List.

Currently, with the massive number of help documents we've got, this index lives across 13 files...`whlsti0.htm` though `whlsti12.htm`.

We are trying to capture that HTML for a separate project, but we need a single file which is, in essence, a concatenation of all 13 files into a single document. Is there a menu option somewhere that forces the output into a single file? Or am I looking at a cut-n-paste job?

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no. Get ready to cut and paste.